# Set DataMapper :order parameters from querystring params

Tags: ruby, datamapper

As I'm not yet fluent in Ruby, I'm having struggling to construct an elegant solution for sorting in my Rails3/DataMapper project.

The DataMapper examples show how to use symbols with `asc` or `desc` parameters to order restuls.  For example:

```
Document.all(:order => [:created_at.desc])
```

What would be the best way to convert `params[:sort]` and  `params[:direction]` to an acceptable format for DataMapper?

For lack of a better idea, this is what I have so far:

```
sort_order = (params[:sort] || 'created_at').to_sym
sort_obj = params[:sort_dir] == 'desc' ? sort_order.desc : sort_order.asc
Document.all(:order => [sort_obj])
```

It works, but feels clunky.  I'm certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found another way to do this, but I'm not confident that this is the best way to go:

```
sort = DataMapper::Query::Operator.new(params[:sort], params[:sort_dir])
Document.all(:order => [sort])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try doing something with `send`, like this:

```
Document.all(:order => [sort_order.send(params[:sort_dir] == "desc" ? :desc : :asc)])
```

I think your way is easier to understand though.